# Get server date time with different timezone

Tags: java, datetime

I want to show server date time to client side which has same status of server datetime. This date is used to achieve some schedule-wise feature. I do following steps:

> - Fetched initial date time from server and just calculated time
>     `date.getTime()` difference.
> - Add time diff to client datetime
> - Update client time using Timer of GWT

It is working fine when server timezone and client timezone both are same. But it gives me wrong calculation with different timezone.

Just example:
if my client time is Indian timezone

> ((UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi)

and 
sever timezone is

> ((UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada))

so it calculates wrong server date.

how can I show current server time with different timezone of server and client without making frequently server request?

Note: The solution should be universal timezone.

**Edit:**

I used RPC Mechanism and returning `new Date().getTime()` from server to client.
And in success method, The client side code:

```
final String serverDate;
            final DateTimeFormat fmt = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(dateFormat);
            if(dateFormat!=null){
                serverDate = fmt.format(result.getServerDate());
            }else{
                serverDate = result.getServerDate().toString();
            }
            setDateTime(serverDate,widget);
            final long dateDiff = result.getServerDate().getTime()-new Date().getTime();
            Timer timer = new Timer() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    long currenrDate=new Date().getTime()+dateDiff;
                    Date date=new Date(currenrDate);
                    String serverDate = fmt.format(date);
                    setDateTime(serverDate,widget);
                    WorkFlowSessionFactory.putValue(WorkFlowSesisonKey.SERVER_DATE_TIME,date);  

                }
            };
            timer.scheduleRepeating(10000);
```

Comment: Please edit your question to provide additional details.  What have you tried?  Is it pure Java on both client and server?  How are you transmitting values between them?  When you say "client" do you mean client JavaScript in a browser - that's completely different.  Please be precise.  Thanks.

Comment: `Server and client means two different machines` If server machine is having different timezone and that time I need to show at client machine. The war build up in gwt technology. it's pure java script. I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try some thing like this?

```
    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    f.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    Date date=new Date();
    System.out.println(f.format(date));   // current UTC time

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
    System.out.println(f.format(cal.getTime()));// current client side time in UTC

    Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal2.setTime(date);
    cal2.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, -8);
    cal2.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    System.out.println(f.format(cal2.getTime()));// current server side time in UTC
```